# How to scroll content horizontally left or right when you swipe it with your finger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing mobile application and I want to swipe the image inside `div` when user swipe with their finger, `div` should scroll. But here in my example entire page is scrolling with the scroll of the `div`. I want my `div` to scroll like this "http://smoothtouchscroll.com/"
   `
    
    
    
    
        jQuery SmoothTouchScroll

```
    <!-- the CSS for Smooth Touch Scroll -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/smoothTouchScroll.css" />

    <!-- Styles for my specific scrolling content -->
    <style type="text/css">
        #touchScroller
        {
        top:70%;
            width:100%;
            height: 30%;
            /* position: relative; */
            position:absolute;
            background-color:red;
        }

        /* Replace the last selector for the type(s) of element(s) you have in
           your scroller.
           If you have images use #touchScroller div.scrollableArea img,
           If you have div's use #touchScroller div.scrollableArea div,
           if you have links use #touchScroller div.scrollableArea a,
           or add several selectors if you have mixed content
           ...and so on. */
        #touchScroller div.scrollableArea a
        {
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 5px;
            /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
               block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
               accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
        }

    </style>
    <!-- jQuery - Get it from Google API's -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI - contains only widget -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery kinetic -->
    <script src="../js/jquery.kinetic.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Smooth Touch Scroll -->
    <script src="../js/jquery.smoothTouchScroll.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p style="position:fixed"> Welcome to yourStory Pvt Ltd </p>
    <div id="touchScroller">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/field.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="field" style="left:0%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/gnome.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="gnome" style="left:30%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/pencils.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="pencils" style="left:60%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/golf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="golf" style="left:90%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/river.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="river" style="left:120%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/train.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="train" style="left:150%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/leaf.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="leaf" style="left:180%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/dog.jpg" alt="Demo image" id="dog" style="left:210%;width:30%;height:100%;position:absolute;background-size:100% 100%;"/></a>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            $("#touchScroller").smoothTouchScroll({ continuousScrolling: true });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

`

Comment: hi robjez, i have done according to you,but when i scroll the image entire page get scroll.I want only inner div should scroll.This is not what i want.Is there ant another way,please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
first you put <div id="touchScroller"> inside another div ie <div class="sliderdiv"><div id="touchScroller"></div><div>. and place the 'sliderdiv' as per your wish in your page.
and change your style to below mentioned . dont give your touchScroller to position absolute.

     #touchScroller { width: 100%; height: 330px; position: relative; background-color: red; }
     #touchScroller div.scrollableArea a { position: relative; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0 5px; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
```